# Are questions seeking an explanation for a concept related to a problem acceptable?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions, site-recommendation

For example, I have an issue with garbage collector pressure affecting my program. I've been trying solutions from the internet, but they all seem to decrease performance. I suspect I'm missing some sort of fundamental concept, but I can only post the code that I changed with a brief description of how it's used and not the full code.

Something like:

> I observed bad performance based on "some tool or performance counters".
> I tried A, here's how I changed my code:
> `<some code bits>`.
> Here is "some tool or performance counters" output before and after the change:
> `<some console outputs>`.
> Why is this decreasing performance, and how was I supposed to implement this to increase performance?

Is a question like that on-topic on Stack Overflow, in Software Engineering, or nowhere? Is it useful to others without the main program where the issue is happening?

Comment: It's the opposite, as my question is very specific (to the point where I'm not sure it would be useful to a broad audience)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GC tuning is <s>*hard*</s> practically an art form with its own graduate thesis attached to it.  Without knowing the **exact** details or at least *enough* details to be able to replicate, test and validate the tuning locally, we're going to have a very rough go at helping you out.

It's not that we *wouldn't* want to help you, or that this advice *isn't* valuable.  The very nature of what you're asking requires us to be much more in context than your average question, and because we can't get that far in context - either because you can't provide more details, or we can't get access to the specific hardware architectures you're dealing with - we wouldn't be able to answer the question.